# difference between trisomy and partial trisomy

Tags: genetics

Trisomy is having 3 chromosomes but then what is partial trisomy ?. I was reading about Patau syndrome and it is called trisomy 13 ( because instead of usual 2 chromosomes,it has 3 chromosomes). it was also wriiten that 20% cases are PARTIAL TRISOMIC...what is the meaning of partial trisomic?

Comment: I assume you checked Google first? The first result looks like it covers this (https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/chromosome-6-partial-trisomy-6q/) - are you asking for further explanation of some aspect of this?

Comment: no, actually i was reading from the slides given by my professor

Answer (score 1):

Any organism with a partial polyploidy has got some tissues with a different number of chromosome set, unlike the rest of cell tissues. 
These situations are often consequences of meiosis error and are more common in plants than in any other organism.

Comment: I think the OP's question is "What does it tell about the genetics of an individual if this individual has partial trisomy?". I don't think the question was "What are the health consequences of partial trisomy?" nor "How does partial trisomy comes to exist?"

Comment: Partial trisomy is just an example of a partial polyploidy. So actually I think my answer is short but straight to the point.